# How to determine whether a web server will ask for client certificates in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, tls1.2

Within Microsoft IIS, there is a setting which controls whether the web server will prompt the user for a client certificate (assuming the user is interacting with the server via a browser).  This is in the "SSL Settings" in IIS Manager -> Requires SSL -> Require.

If this is set up, the browser will prompt the user to select a client certificate, which is all fine and dandy if you *want* to use client certificates for mutual TLS.  But my objective is to detect when a Microsoft IIS-hosted web site is misconfigured to prompt for client certificates when mutual TLS is not desired.  And do so in an automated way (ideally in C#).

One option is to use something like Selenium browser automation (which is my fallback option, though I haven't fully verified that will work), but I was hoping for a more direct way to detect this.

Based on my (admittedly quick skim) of [RFC 5246](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.4), this involves the server sending a "Certificate Request" message back to the  client.

I've poked around the [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-7.0) class a bit, but don't see an obvious way to detect the Certificate Request message.  The [LocalCertificateSelectionCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.localcertificateselectioncallback?view=net-7.0) seems to be called regardless of whether the server is actually asking for a client certificate or not (based on testing against a server that does not prompt for a client cert).

Any ideas or pointers for how detecting the client certificate prompt might be accomplished?

Comment: Assuming you have access to the server (i.e., you aren't trying to do this from s browser) writing a PowerShell script to do this (using the IIS Snap-in would be a piece of cake

Comment: I won't have direct access to the server, except via an HTTP (web) connection.

Comment: I believe the handshake happens under the covers for the most part.  But, if you make a request to a server and not provide a client cert when the server demands it, you should get a 403 response.  Depending on the server, that may be further specified as 403.7: ‘Client Certificate Required’ or 403.16: ‘Client Certificate is Untrusted or Invalid'.  I think...

Comment: Interesting that `LocalCertificateSelectionCallback` is indeed called all the times (even if you connect to something like `https://www.microsoft.com`). So like the other comment indicated, you should observe the 403 errors and send out client certificates when needed.

Comment: Selenium browser automation, while also an alternative, may involve more complexity as it launches a browser to test the website rather than simulating HTTP requests directly.

Comment: Right - I've done Selenium browser automation before.  The thing I'm not sure about with that option is detecting the client cert popup, because it isn't in the DOM.  But that isn't the focus of my question here and maybe mentioning it was a distraction.